# Can I pass existing Cassandra session to TransactionService?

Tags: scalardb

1. In Scalardb, would `TransactionService` create a new session every time I instantiate it?
2. Can I create a `TransactionService` at application start up and use the same session throughout the application lifecycle?
3. If the connection breaks, would TransactionService throw an exception which my application can handle and try to reconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. In Scalardb, would TransactionService create a new session every time I instantiate it?

Session is always reused once created if `TransactionService` is properly created with Guice since it is configured to do singleton. (This is also the answer for the 2nd question)

> 3. If the connection breaks, would TransactionService throw an exception which my application can handle and try to reconnect?

The connection will be re-established automatically so you don't have to worry about it.
(It is taken care by the datastax java driver)